# Can a caster stack castings of Leomund's Tiny Hut on the exact same area?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stacking

RAW, can a caster stack castings of *Leomund's tiny hut* on the exact same area?

As in, when the remaining duration is greater than the casting time, they would ritual-cast it a second time.

(The motive for needing to do this is to make the hut more resistant to *disintegrate*/*dispel magic*. Layered effects need to be taken down one by one, a la the good old *prismatic wall*).

Answer (score 11):

### You can cast it but it won't do anything.

PHB 205:

> The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap.

If your goal is to keep a constant Tiny Hut up without interruptions, then yes, you can cast it multiple times and the spell will constantly stay up--the second hut will take effect as soon as the first one runs out (or is otherwise dispelled or destroyed). However, it does waste a bit of the duration of the second spell, since the clock on the second casting starts as soon as it is cast.

Comment: Note that the end of this sentence under ["Combining Magical Effects"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CombiningMagicalEffects) was changed in errata to add: ", or the most recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent and their durations overlap." This might affect the suggested resolution of the spells in your answer.

Comment: I don't see how this means it won't do anything. You have five simultaneous tiny huts in play. All but one are suppressed by the the latest casting. If that one is dispelled/disintegrated though, the others are still there, so the second-latest casting is still running.

Comment: Although now I'm not sure how "Spells and other magical effects can't extend through the dome or be cast through it." should apply here. Arguably, even if you cast from *exactly* the center of the existing hut, the magical effect of the new dome is "extending through" the existing one (infinitely thin force fields are weird for defining "through").